# GSL function to replace catlas_daxpby

Tags: gsl, atlas

I want to replace catlas_daxpby function from ATLAS library with a GSL equivalent function. Is there any?

Answer (score 0):

There's the [Level 1 GSL BLAS Interface](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Level-1-GSL-BLAS-Interface.html) which indicates that there's a function:

```
int gsl_blas_daxpy (double alpha, const gsl_vector * x, gsl_vector * y)
```

There are also [these vector operations](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Vector-operations.html) that might have what you're looking for.